# Cauchy Schwarz inequality and the angle between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I’ve looked at other answers on the site and non seem to go into enough detail to make me satisfied.

With the Cauchy Schwarz inequality it’s commonly said that we can define the angle between two vectors as $\cos(\theta)$ has the same range.

How is this possible? Sure we can say that these two things have the same range but why do they have to completely agree? And also why does it have to be the ANGLE, why not just some random number?

Answer (score 0):

Inner products, including squared lengths, are invariant under rotations, so without loss of generality two vectors $\vec{a},\,\vec{b}$ can be written as $\vec{a}=a\vec{i},\,\vec{b}=u\vec{i}+v\vec{j},\,u^2+v^2=b^2$. This is a diagram-friendly choice, regardless of the vector space's dimension. In this coordinate system, $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=au=ab\cos\theta$, with $\theta$ the angle between the vectors. This angle is then $\arccos\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{ab}$, also invariant under rotations.

Comment: I like this explanation but I was hoping for something on the lines of why the inequality can be related to the angle in a more direct manner. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JakeRose The inequality can be restated as $|\cos\theta|\le 1$, which is obvious once we switch to the above coordinate system.

Comment: Have you not assumed the property of the inner product with this though? Where you say $a\dot b = \cos(\theta)$?

Comment: @JakeRose No; you just notice $u=b\cos\theta$ from a right-angled triangle.